# Explicit Mapping to show that positive even integers and integers divisible by 3 have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

So I'm really confused about what this question is asking and how to show it. 
I've started by trying to map out each set in my head
ie. $\{\dots,-6,-3,0,3,6,\dots\} \{2,4,6,8,\dots\}$.

I've done some research and it seems like the correct set I should be using for divisible by $3$ is $\{0, 3, -3, 6, -6,\dots\}$ (so that I have a starting point).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Here's a bijection $f\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ that is not a piecewise function:
$$
f(m) = \frac{\frac{1 + (-1)^{m+1}}{2} + (-1)^m m}{2}
$$
See if you can combine this bijection with some other bijections to solve your problem.

Comment: So for in the case of this problem the divis by 3 bijection would be that except with a (3) in front. and the bijection of the even positives would be f(m) = 2m. How would I combine these two bijections? I'm not sure I understand what that means

Comment: What we're doing here is:
\begin{align*}
\{2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots\}
&\to \{1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots\} &\text{by doing what?}\\
&\to \{0, 1, -1, 2, -2, \ldots\} &\text{by using $f$} \\
&\to \{0, 3, -3, 6, -6, \ldots\} &\text{by doing what?}
\end{align*}

Comment: That just got me more confused. I know you're dividing by 2 in the first and then multiplying by 3 for the other. I honestly don't even understand what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Am I trying to find a function that maps 2, 4, 6, 8 to 0, 3, -3, 6, -6?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Start with any even integer, say $n$. In the first arrow, $n$ turns into $n/2$. After the second arrow, what does $n/2$ turn into? Well just replace $m$ with $n/2$ in the above function.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you, but would my formula in OP be the function/answer?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "essentially it's forming a set such like $\{2,0,4,3,6,-3,\ldots\}$". Since the problem asks you to find a bijection which is a function, not a set of integers.

**HINT:** It's much easier to do by steps. First find a bijection between the positive even numbers and the integers, then compose it with a bijection between the integers and the integers divisible by $3$.

Comment: How would I compose the two of them? I have my two bijections (see Adriano's comment) but I'm not quite sure what you guys mean to do now

Comment: Do you know what a composition of functions is? It means, essentially, applying one and then another.

Comment: so like f(g(m))?

Comment: Exactly like that.

Comment: So would I just replace m in f(m) of Adriano's comment (but with a 3 in front) with f(2m)?

Comment: Something like that, I suppose.